# How to merge data from two columns into one with a + sign using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, string-concatenation

I have 2 columns in this format in a csv.

```
Drug    Product(Predicted)
#N/A    acetaldehyde
#N/A    nicotine
#N/A    resin
#N/A    rosa
#N/A    eliglustat
#N/A    valpromide
#N/A    clostridium
#N/A    ambenonium
solution    valpromide
solution    valpromide
solution    valpromide
solution    valpromide
solution    valpromide
solution    valpromide
solution    valpromide
solution    valpromide
solution    valpromide
#N/A    amiloride
#N/A    valsartÃ¡n
#N/A    manitol
#N/A    hipromelosa
#N/A    fosfato disÃ³dico
#N/A    fosfato disÃ³dico
#N/A    agalsidase beta
#N/A    enoxaparin sodium
solution    warfarine
#N/A    eliglustat
#N/A    silver
#N/A    silver
```

The output I am looking for is that, create a new column and whenever there is an entry present in the drug column(ignore all N/A), add that entry to the new column by concatenating the 2 columns with a plus sign and get an output csv

For example:

```
New column
solution + valpromide
solution + valpromide
solution + warfarine
```

I am new to pandas so I wanted to know how this can be done using the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) with [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['new'] = df['Drug'].str.cat(df['Product(Predicted)'], na_rep='', sep='+').str.strip('+')
```

Or replace missing values to empty strings before merge:

```
df['new'] = (df['Drug'].fillna('') + '+' + df['Product(Predicted)']).str.strip('+')
```

---

```
print (df)
       Drug Product(Predicted)                  new
0       NaN       acetaldehyde         acetaldehyde
1       NaN           nicotine             nicotine
2       NaN              resin                resin
3       NaN               rosa                 rosa
4       NaN         eliglustat           eliglustat
5       NaN         valpromide           valpromide
6       NaN        clostridium          clostridium
7       NaN         ambenonium           ambenonium
8  solution         valpromide  solution+valpromide
9  solution         valpromide  solution+valpromide
```

If want remove rows with `NaN`s in `drug` column:

```
df1 = df.dropna(subset=['Drug'])
df1['new'] = df1['Drug'] + '+' + df1['Product(Predicted)']
print (df)
       Drug Product(Predicted)                  new
8  solution         valpromide  solution+valpromide
9  solution         valpromide  solution+valpromide
```

Comment: @BilzzM - Do you need last paragraph? Remove these rows? Or need output NaN by `df['new'] = df['Drug'].str.cat(df['Product(Predicted)'], sep='+')` ?

Comment: I just need a concatenated string for each row which don't contain a NA.

Comment: @BilzzM - Yes, and whats happen with rows if `drug` have `NaN`s ?

Comment: @BilzzM - there are 3 possible solutions - removed these rows in my last paragraph, or ignore them like my first paragraph or stay `NaN` in output column by `df['new'] = df['Drug'].str.cat(df['Product(Predicted)'], sep='+')`

Comment: so only drugs contain NaN. So whenever there is a NaN in a drug column, I just want to ignore that. Trying your solutions, thanks a lot :)

Comment: One more doubt, actually I have changed my csv and added another column called filename. What I want to do is keep the filename as a separate column so to track the filenames for which I am getting output (concatenated string). So, I don't want to concatenate the filename column but want it as a separate column in my csv. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @BilzzM - Not sure if understand, because my code not concatenate column `filename`, not used it. So if add it there is no change. Or something missing? How is popssible my code have influence for `filename` column?

Comment: What I am asking is, I have a added a third column called Filenames. So what I want to find out in my output csv is the filenames for which I have got the concatenated strings, i.e. df1['new']. How do I output this to a csv by keeping the filenames in one column and df1['new'] in another column

Comment: Yes, so use `df[['Filename','new']].to_csv(file, index=False)`

Comment: If I do, df1['new'] = df1['Drug'] + '+' + df1['Product(Predicted)'] + df1['Filename'], I get one string containing all but I  want df1['Filename'] as a separate column in the csv

Comment: @BilzzM - So not working `df1[['Filename','new']].to_csv(file, index=False)` ? It filter only column `Filename` and `new` and write to csv

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have null values in your dataframe, mentioned as null, then I suggest you do the following :

`df["drug"].replace("#N/A", np.nan, inplace = True)`

Once, you have replaced the missing values with null, the answer is just one single line of code

`df["new_col"] = df["drug"] + "  +  " + df["Product"]`

The above code, will return an output of null, if either of the column, product or drug is null.

Hope this helps.